# Disable optimizing imports when writing JSX in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea

When I reformat the code, IntelliJ IDEA always replaces single quote with double quote in `import` section.

Like in below code, `'react'` is replaced with `"react"`, and it is showing "imports optimized". I did not find a place to disable this for JSX. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: So you want ' instead of "?

Comment: @AndrewLi Yeah. I want single quote, but IntelliJ IDEA replaces single quote with double quote after reformatting.

Comment: Have you tried changing code style?

Comment: @AndrewLi The answer posted works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Settings

Look for Editor > Code Styles > Javascript

On the last tab "Other" change "Generated Code" "Quote Marks" to Single Quote...

Answer (score 0):

I think this has change location:

I got version: 2017.3.3 built on Jan 16, 2018.

Steps:

```
Ctrl + Alt + S  // Open Settings
Click Editor > Code Styles > Language(JS | TS)
Tab Punctuation(This is what changes)
Use **single** quotes **always**
```